# What is the GCS base PATH?

Tags: path, google-cloud-storage

D'oh!

I was trying to add a directory to my PATH and made a typo that deleted the base path.

I still have access to my Google Cloud Shell, but I do not have a list of the directories in the base PATH.  Can anyone tell me what that would be so that I can restore it?

Answer (score 0):

If you close out of GCS and reopen it after some time the default PATH is restored!